# Discord bot's no spamming feature isn't working

Tags: javascript, discord

So I have been attempting to make an anti-spam function on a discord bot, but have look over my code and it all seems to work, but it doesn't. I am new to javascript, so I'm not sure whats wrong... Everything else works on my bot, just not this. I am only pasting the part of my code involving the antispam:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
 const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
 });
function antispam() {
var spam = 0;
}
client.on('ready', () => {
setInterval(antispam(), 5000);
 });
client.on('message', msg => {
if (spam > 10) {
client.channels.get('546117125702680596').send('Hey! You are sending messages too quickly!');
}
});
function antispam() {
var spam = 0;
}
client.on('message', msg => {
var spam = spam + 1;
});
client.login('token');
```

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overfow!

Several issue here:

- You're declaring `antispam` twice, declare functions always once
- Your interval doesn't do anything. It calls `antispam` what creates `spam` inside the scope of `antispam` what gets deleted immediately after `antispam` finishes executing
- You're declaring `client.on('message'...` twice. Again, just do it once
- You're declaring `client.on('ready'...) twice.
- If you increase `spam` inside `client.on('message'...)` that `spam` variable will be useless just as in `antispam`. You don't access it anywhere (you also couldn't if you would try to)

So here's a solution that should work:

```
// To count the "spam level"
const spam = 0;

// Increase spam everytime someone writes something
client.on('message', msg => {
    // Check if spam level is already too high
    if (spam > 10) {
        client.channels.get('546117125702680596').send('Hey! You are sending messages too quickly!');
    } else {
        spam++;
    }
});

// Decrease the spam level, otherwise nobody can't send message until the bot gets restarted
setInterval(() => {
    if (spam > 0) {
        spam--;
    }
}, 10000); // Let's decrease it every 10 seconds
```

Your whole code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
// To count the "spam level"
const spam = 0;

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

// Increase spam everytime someone writes something
client.on('message', msg => {
    // Check if spam level is already too high
    if (spam > 10) {
        client.channels.get('546117125702680596').send('Hey! You are sending messages too quickly!');
    } else {
        spam++;
    }
});

// Decrease the spam level, otherwise nobody can't send message until the bot gets restarted
setInterval(() => {
    if (spam > 0) {
        spam--;
    }
}, 10000); // Let's decrease it every 10 seconds 

client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// To count the "spam level"
const spam = 0;

// Increase spam everytime someone writes something
client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.author.bot) return 
    // Check if spam level is already too high
    if (spam > 10) {
        client.channels.get('546117125702680596').send('Hey! You are sending messages too quickly!');
    } else {
        spam++;
    }
});

// Decrease the spam level, otherwise nobody can't send message until the bot gets restarted
setInterval(() => {
    if (spam > 0) {
        spam--;
    }
}, 10000); // Let's decrease it every 10 seconds
```

The code provided by CodeF0x is good , but make sure to add:

```
if(msg.author.bot) return
```

If the message being sent was by a bot, it will ignore them. IF YOU DO NOT add this to your code, get prepared for your bot to spam. It will respond to itself due to that if statement missing (especially since every time one sends a message, the spam variable will increase). So yeah, happy coding!